# Prismic embedded url for a video does not load

Tags: html, reactjs, prismic.io

```
  <video
    controls
    className={"w-full h-full object-contain"}
    loop
    autoPlay
    muted
  >
    <source
      src={videoUrl.embed_url}
      type="video/mp4"
      className={"relative z-[100000]"}
    />
  </video>
```

If I put static(local) video src -> it works. But external video URL - doesn't.

What can cause this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i would try creating a frame. and sorry im not sure of the cause of the problem

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<video
    controls
    className="w-full h-full object-contain"
    loop
    autoPlay=""
    muted="muted"
    playsinline=""
  >
    <source
      src={videoUrl.embed_url}
      type="video/mp4"
      className={"relative z-[100000]"}
    />
  </video>
```